# Change Value of all Columns of a Row with a VBA Form button click

Tags: forms, vba, excel, worksheet

I have made a beautiful form for adding a bill to my new database. Now I need the 'Submit' button to calculate and organize the information in the sheets of my workbook. To keep this question simple, I am first focusing on one worksheet which I have named **billData**. I will need each entered field of the form to auto fill into the next available row on the **billData** worksheet.

Here is what I have come up with so far:

```
Private Sub NB_SubmitButton_Click()
'NB stands for New Bill

Dim OwnerName As String
Dim ExpenseName As String
Dim CycleValue As String 'such as every day, every week, every month etc.
Dim OnValue As String 'such as Monday, the 5th, the 10th, etc.
Dim AndValue As String 'such as 19th, 24th, etc.
Dim DueAmount As Currency
Dim SavedAmount As Currency
Dim NoteValue As String
Dim x As Long

NoteValue = NB_NoteTextBox.Value
SavedAmount = NB_SavedAmountTextBox.Value
DueAmount = NB_DueAmountTextBox.Value
AndValue = NB_AndComboBox.Value
OnValue = NB_OnComboBox.Value
CycleValue = NB_CycleComboBox.Value
ExpenseName = NB_ExpenseNameTextBox.Value
OwnerName = NB_OwerNameTextBox.Value
x = 1

For x = 1 To Rows.Count
    If Worksheets("billData").Range(Cells(x, 1)).Value = "" Or _ 
      IsEmpty(Worksheets("billData").Cells(x, 1).Value) Then
        Worksheets("billData").Range(Cells(x, 2)).Value = OwnerName
        Worksheets("billData").Range(Cells(x, 4)).Value = ExpenseName
        Worksheets("billData").Range(Cells(x, 7)).Value = CycleValue
        Worksheets("billData").Range(Cells(x, 8)).Value = OnValue
        Worksheets("billData").Range(Cells(x, 9)).Value = DueAmount
        Worksheets("billData").Range(Cells(x, 10)).Value = SavedAmount
        Worksheets("billData").Cells(x, 11).Value = NoteValue
    Else
    End If
Next x
```

When I run the **For** code through the Immediate, I keep getting an error message:

> *Compile Error: Next without For*

Then, when I run all the code, fill in the fields on the form and click the 'Submit' button, I get this error:

> *Run-Time Error '9': Subscript out of range*

Also, Is there a better way to obtain my goal? Should I be using VLookup?

Edited to add screenshot:

[image]

Comment: Error9 suggests there is no worksheet named "billData" in the active workbook.  It would help though to indicate which line is highlighted when the error occurs.  You cannot run multi-line code blocks via the Immediate pane.

Comment: This is a [screenshot](http://www.somaofchrist.org/Testing/img/billDataVisual.png) of the Object Viewer. It apears that __billData__ is the correct name for it. The one line only rule in the immediate pane explains the _Next without For_ problem. I am still getting this _Run-Time Error '9': Subscript out of range_ error though. If __billData__ is the correct Name then what else could it be?

Comment: `billData` is the sheet's code module name: the name on the sheet tab is `Bill Data`, so either use `billData.Range(...)` or `Worksheets("Bill Data").Range(...)`

Comment: when I used `billData.Range(...)`it gave me the error `Run-Time Error '1004': Method 'Range' of object '_Worksheet' failed`. Then when I used `Worksheets("Bill Data").Range(...)` it gave me the error `Run-Time Error '1004': Application-defined or object-defined error`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
'x = 1 'you don't need this...

Dim sht As Worksheet
Set sht = Worksheets("Bill Data")

For x = 1 To Rows.Count
    If Len(sht.Cells(x, 1).Value) = 0 Then
        With sht.Rows(x)
            '? what goes in ColA ?
            .Cells(2).Value = OwnerName
            .Cells(4).Value = ExpenseName
            .Cells(7).Value = CycleValue
            .Cells(8).Value = OnValue
            .Cells(9).Value = DueAmount
            .Cells(10).Value = SavedAmount
            .Cells(11).Value = NoteValue
        End With
    End If
Next x
```